# How to Display a keyboard in an Android Application?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Trigger the soft keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209131/how-to-trigger-the-soft-keyboard)

Any one please help me to display a keyboard in my app. I want to show my keyboard when i click on the textfield

Comment: Do you want to show some keyboard, or a specific one?

Comment: i want an alphabetic keyboard no numerals at all

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't have to do nothing : I you have a textfield and the user clicks on it, the framework/OS will manage the keyboard for you.